# How do I force Angular to run a validation cycle (for built in validation)?

Tags: angularjs

I need to **update the model** of a text field, then **fire validation** to show the user visual feedback that it is a valid entry.

I have tried two methods, but I can only get one of the requirements to work at the expense of the other.

**First option**: http://jsfiddle.net/TZQjS/

```
  // changing the model in controller updates the field
  // but the `required` directive will not run.
  $scope.populateValid = function () {
     $scope.testField = 'yes, yes, yes';
  }
```

**Second option**:http://jsfiddle.net/R3b7Y/

```
  // `$setViewValue()` of the ngModel API updates the model 
  // but two-way binding seems to fail
  $scope.populateValid = function () {
     $scope.testForm.testField.$setViewValue('yes, yes, yes');
  }
```

How can I make both things happen, that is update the field with text, and also run validation immediately after?

I have read in places of `$parsers` and `$formatters` but I cannot understand how to use them in this context - many discussions talk about them in terms of custom validation directives.

Comment: Changing the model should fire the needed events, http://jsfiddle.net/FHXVT/ this example shows the field highlighting correctly. Removing the ng-dirty class from the css rules seems to apply the correct highlighting of the input.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! So that means ng-dirty is not being appended to the field. When the model is updated dirty should be set to true and this class must be appended right? Am I missing another function call here, or should I file a bug?

Comment: I don't believe that to be a bug. `$pristine; // Boolean. True if the user has not yet modified the form.`
`$dirty // Boolean. True if the user has already modified the form.`
`$valid // Boolean.True if the the form passes the validation.`
`$invalid// Boolean. True if the the form doesn't pass the validation.` Taken from this blog [post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way).

Comment: I see, so that's really targeted toward user input. But as you can see this is less than ideal because the field is marked invalid straight away, without waiting for the user to write something. Would you know if setting those properties like $pristine etc fires any events?

Comment: See @Phil Toms answer below, having the `input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty` css rule will prevent the input from being marked invalid before the user has a chance to enter any values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation is firing as expected in your first option, but you can't see it because your second CSS rule is too stringent. You have:

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    background-color: #FA787E;
}

input.ng-valid.ng-dirty {
    background-color: #78FA89;
}
```

ng-valid and ng-dirty are [complementary](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.css-styling) so they can be used together or separately as required. If you use them together as you have, you are ANDing them. A model has to be valid AND dirty to match the second rule. But in your case you only want to show that the model has been validated, so remove ng-dirty from the second rule.

Notice that if you remove ng-dirty from both rules, the view will show invalid before the user has entered anything. This isn't what we usually want, so here is a good example of when the classes should be used together.